# Print "A" presented in HEX (printf("\0x41"))

Tags: c

How to make `printf("\0x41")`; to rint 'A' letter. I know, that `\0` means end of line, but how to deal when I need to print character presented in `HEX`?

Comment: \0 is the null terminator (meaning end of string). Not the same as "end of line".

Comment: Your are very wrong about `\0`!!!!

Comment: @Bathsheba: No, of course. I am supporting your comment. User1501700 is very wrong in his believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the leading 0 in the hexadecimal character literal:

```
printf("\x41");
```

Integer literals use `0x` prefix, characters use `\x`.

You might also want to add a linefeed to make sure it appears:

```
printf("\x41\n");
```

You can of course also print a single character:

```
printf("%c\n", 0x41);
```

or portably:

```
printf("%c\n", 'a');
```

Comment: `Integer literals use 0x prefix, characters use \x.` I didn't know that!! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

`printf("%c", 0x41);`